# Como validar se existe algum arquivo para upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Tenho um form para upload de arquivos:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("importCSV", "Administrador", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "upldFrm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                <div class="form-inline">

                    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />

                    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="enviarForm" />

                </div>

                <label style="color:red; white-space: pre-line">@ViewBag.Message</label>
            }
```

Antes de ser enviado, eu gostaria de validar se o usuário escolheu mesmo um arquivo através de JQuery.

O que tenho é isso:

```
$("#enviarForm").click(function () {
                var file = $("#file");
                alert(file[0].size);
                if (file[0].size <= 0) {
                    alert("Selecione um arquivo!");
                } else {
                    $("#upldFrm").submit();
                }
            });
```

Mas nesse caso, o `size` sempre tem retornado `20` mesmo sem escolher nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a propriedade `files` do `<input/>` de arquivo essa verificação pode ser feita:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#file');
console.log(input.files.length);
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (this.querySelector('#file').files.length > 0) {
    alert('arquivo está selecionado');
  } else {
    alert('arquivo não está selecionado');
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<br/><input type="submit"/>
</form>
```